# PKCS12 - private key protection

Tags: rsa

I know that PKCS12 private key is protected by a password, but what is actually done with the password ? Does it use PBKDF to derive the key from password ? That would be a problem as if you change the password, the private key would no longer be the same.

Is it like truecrypt volume, the password derives a key which is itself used to decrypt the private key ?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to your questions are all in the PKCS #12 specification. I am going to take as reference the recent [RFC 7292](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292), which corresponds to "PKCS #12: Personal Information Exchange Syntax v1.1".

It is important to note that the private key is not derived from the password. What is derived from the password is the symmetric key that protects the PKCS12 object, which is completely unrelated to the private key. In fact, the PKCS #12 standard can also be used for protecting certificates, CRLs, or other miscellaneous information. Moreover, password-based protection is not the only method. It can use public-key encryption or even no encryption at all, so information remains unprotected.

In the password-based protection mode, the symmetric key used is derived using PBKDF2. In particular:

> [...] Specifically, PBES2 should be used as encryption scheme, with PBKDF2
> as the key derivation function.

Comment: "the symmetric key that protects the PKCS12 object", does it mean that even public infos (certificates) are encrypted ? I would have think that only private key section would be concerned by password-based encryption.

Comment: It means that even public info (e.g., certificates) _can_ be encrypted in a PKCS12 object. In fact, the standard permits the PKCS12 object to contain "opaque data objects, at the user's discretion", that is, anything you want. However, it is usually used for storing encrypted private keys.

Comment: PKCS12 *can* contain opaque data, but all uses I have seen contain privatekey strongly encrypted and related cert(s) weakly encrypted (for no obvious reason) and all HMACed. The standard allows different passwords for HMAC and each encrypted bag, but this makes the UI complicated and isn't much implemented. The password(s) is indeed used to derive encryption (and MAC) keys and do not alter the protected data including privatekey; if the UI doesn't allow changing password directly you can (always?) extract or import from one password(s) and export the same data under a different password(s).